# HABTM association dropdown select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu, html-select, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to create a dropdown select on a form. I have a HABTM association between professors and classrooms:

Classroom Model:

```
class Classroom < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :professors
end
```

Professor Model:

```
class Professor < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :classrooms
end
```

Strong Params:

```
def classroom_params
  params.require(:classroom).permit(:name, :professor_ids => [])
end
```

I am trying to find a way to use `f.select` instead of `select_tag` inside the form. But when I do it, the database does not save the values. This way works:

```
<%= form_for @classroom do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
  <% array = Professor.all.map { |professor| [professor.user.name, professor.id] } %>
  <%= select_tag "classroom[professor_ids][]", options_for_select(array) %>
<% end %>
```

But I am trying like that and it is not working:

```
<%= form_for @classroom do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
  <% array = Professor.all.map { |professor| [professor.user.name, professor.id] } %>
  <%= f.select :professor_ids, options_for_select(array) %>
<% end %>
```

The view works correctly but when I submit the form, the value doesn't go to to the classroom_params. I tried to debug it stopping the controller after the submit and I got this:

[image]

The params came correctly with all the information submitted, but the classroom_params came missing the professor_ids.
Is there a way to do this dropdown using `f.select`?

Comment: what is `cfg` in controller? Please attach controller code.

Comment: It is just something I wrote to stop it and then see the params at the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You whitelisted the array of 'professor_ids', but your 'select' input returns 1 string (`"prefessor_ids" => "2"` from you screenshot). Maybe you want to set the select as 'multiple'? (I have not tested it, but i think params will be whitelisted correctly after that)

```
<%= form_for @classroom do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
  <%= s.collection_select :professor_ids, Professor.all, :id, :name, multiple: true  %>
<% end %>
```

where

```
class Professor
  ...
  delegate :name, to: :user
end
```

***Update***

You probably don't have 'cfg' variable in your controller action.

Comment: The cfg is just to stop it and get the params in the prompt. This way still doesn't work. It continues to not saving the professor value in the db table.

Comment: Of course, just leave it they way you had it, just add the 'multiple' param: `f.select :professor_ids, options_for_select(array), {}, multiple: true`